# SQLALCHEMY ignore accents on query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, diacritics

Considering my users can save data as "café" or "cafe", I need to be able to search on that fields with an accent-insensitive query.

I've found https://github.com/djcoin/django-unaccent/, but I have no idea if it is possible to implement something similar on sqlalchemy.

I'm using PostgreSQL, so if the solution is specific to this database is good to me. If it is  generic solution, it is much much better.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First install the **[unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html)** extension in PostgreSQL with `create extension unaccent;`

Next, declare the SQL function `unaccent` in Python:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import ReturnTypeFromArgs

class unaccent(ReturnTypeFromArgs):
    pass
```

and use it like this:

```
for place in session.query(Place).filter(unaccent(Place.name) == "cafe").all():
    print place.name
```

Make sure you have the correct indexes if you have a large table, otherwise this will result in a full table scan.

Comment: It worked! I had to use unidecode as suggested by Miguel below on the search string. It turned out something like this: `session.query(Place).filter((unaccent(Place.name).ilike(string)))`. It also ignores case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doing this in flask-sqlalchemy gives me `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) user-defined function raised exception
` no matter what. Can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 9):

A simple and database agnostic solution is to write the field(s) that can have accents twice, once with and once without accents. Then you can conduct your searches on the unaccented version.

To generate the unaccented vesrsion of a string you can use [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1).

To automatically assign the unaccented version to the database when a record is inserted or updated you can use the `default` and `onupdate` clauses in the `Column` definition. For example, using Flask-SQLAlchemy you could do something like this:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
def unaccent(context):
    return unidecode(context.current_parameters['some_string'])

class MyModel(db.Model):
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    some_string = db.Column(db.String(128))
    some_string_unaccented = db.Column(db.String(128), default=unaccent, onupdate=unaccent, index=True)
```

Note how I only indexed the unaccented field, because that is the one on which the searches will be made.

Of course before you can search you also have to unaccent the value you are searching for. For example:

```
def search(text):
    return MyModel.query.filter_by(some_string_unaccented = unaccent(text)).all()
```

You can apply the same technique to full text search, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! while I finally used user2716201's approach, I also used your `unidecode` suggestion on the input string. Sorry I can't upvote your answer, apparently I don't currently have enough reputation.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this solution. How does the `unaccent` function work in the `search` function? It returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'current_parameters'`, which seems expected to me...

Comment: this also creates trouble when I am updating another column in the entry and the parameter `some_string` is not provided, as in updating a field indirectly by appending to a relationship in a related model. How to fix it?