# Flask + SQLAlchemy - Updateing with missing context.current_parameters

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

My problem is slightly specific:
In my project i needed to use Miguel's tip for creating unaccented names: [SQLALCHEMY ignore accents on query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433719/sqlalchemy-ignore-accents-on-query/18434127)

My updated code:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
def unaccent(context):
    return unidecode(context.current_parameters['name'])

class MyModel(db.Model):
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64))           # NEW COLUMN 
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    name_unaccented = db.Column(db.String(128), default=unaccent, onupdate=unaccent, index=True)
```

When i update both columns, everything works fine. Everything works fine when i update the only "name" column too.

But i have problem, when i need update only "first_name" column (without updateing "name" column).

When i try this, my statement ending with error:

```
    StatementError: (builtins.KeyError) 'name' [SQL: 'UPDATE subjects SET first_name=?, name_unaccented=? WHERE subjects.id = ?'] [parameters: [{'first_name': 'Some Name', 'subjects_id': 5}]]
```

Have someone idea to fix this problem?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i have "solution".
I had to create another function:

```
def remove_accents(string):
    return unidecode(string).lower()
```

and column 'name_unaccented' manual update after every request from form.

```
 name=form.name.data,
 # update manualy name_unaccented
 name_unaccented=remove_accents(form.name.data),
```

Isn't perferct solution, but for my purposes is okay.

Comment: Nice solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712600/2278511